What part of the brain is the self?
I can see. Therefore my optic nerves must terminate directly on me.  So what part of the brain is the self?

What part of the piano is the music? It comes out of it, so it must be there. It helps to learn how to put words together before making questions out of them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus


I can see. Therefore my optic nerves must terminate directly on me.

False. Your optic nerve (mostly) terminates at the lateral geniculate nucleus. That's not a capsule where the self resides, it's just a transit point for a flow of neurological information on its way to the visual cortex and other regions of the brain.
The naive concept of "the self" can be broken down into various elements. To some extent these various elements can be located in specific regions of the brain. But there is no direct correlation between the whole experience of self and some specific place in the body/brain, or any reason to think that such a thing could be possible.

According to your post, is the self just interactions of the various elements located which generate our sense of self or consciousness but to that I must ask, are some people more self-ish and more conscious than others depending on the connections that occur with the different parts.

Again here I would say that the concept of "the self" is too vague and needs to be broken down. There are efforts to measure the degree of conscious awareness for sure. Measuring degrees of narrative selfhood is also a thing, but very different.

When the visually impaired read braille, they are "seeing" with their fingers.
When you close your eyes, and stick a toe in the pool water to check if it is cold, you are "seeing" with your toes.
Myself is all of me.

Yes, but a brain activity predates ...

I usually make an analogy of the mind with a film, in the sense that the mind cannot be reduced to the electrical signals inside the TV-set (~brain), but it has to be projected and seen by someone; only then, can the semantics and the meaning be realized by the viewer.
In a similar way, you could say that the semantics of a word, concept or phrase do not exist inside the word; but in fact (the semantics) consist of a huge amount of information, spread all over across reality, experiences, books and everyone of us, in a way that no-one can claim the complete understanding of it.
Now, let's go back to the movie. There exists an actor, playing a character. The personality of the character, does not exist neither in the electric signals inside the TV-set (~brain) nor in the movie (~mind) per se. It exists in the personal way the viewer (~self) understands that character.
The self you are talking about is not part of neither the brain, nor the mind.
In Advaita Vedanta (Hindu) philosophy, maya is the limited, purely physical (~brain) and mental (~mind) reality in which our everyday consciousness (~self) has become entangled. Maya is believed to be an illusion, a veiling of the true, unitary Self—the Cosmic Spirit also known as Brahman.
The meaning of this is that what you consider as self is under the illusion that is part of the brain or mind, while these are the containers of it, but in the same sense that a jar contains the space inside it; but that space is not really part of the jar, it's just contained in it.

Unfortunately you do not clarify your definition of the “Self”. There are different definitions in circulation since millenia, according to Vedic speculations, different strands of psychology, models from the philosophy of the mind, …
When equating “the self” with the self-model: The self-model is that part of the world-model of an individual, which contains an integrated and highly abstracted view onto the mental processes of the individual. I take this definition from Thomas Metzinger, for an introduction see Self-model.
In any case, the self is net of mental processes, hence a dynamic structure. It cannot be localized.
Hence to consider the self a part of the brain, a physical structure, seems to me a category error.

X is a point particle iff x exists and x is indivisible.  X is a body iff x exists and x is divisible.  Therefore, x is a point particle or x is a body iff x exists.  If x is a point particle or x is a body then x is matter. Therefore, if x exists then x is matter.  A process lasts some amount of time, and therefore doesn't exist.  To define self as a set of processes means self does not exist.  But I exist.  Hence I am matter.   No category error here.

@leepappas You can indeed create such a classification hierarchy.  But the first line gives me some pause.  How do you know if x is an element has the property "divisible?"  There are lots of nuances hiding in that hierarchy.  You can "divide me vertically with a sword," so in that sense "me" is divisible.  However, it is generally accepted that such a fatal act does not result in two bodies that can be combined again to form "me."  Little nuances like that can shape the implications of such a categorization in ways that the syntax of the categorization might obscure.
